# How can I create a transparent background for discord with CSS?

Tags: css, background, transparent, discord

I am at my first year programming and just learning Java this is why I am completly lost with CSS and need help.
I want to edit this code (not mine)

```
===== CUSTOMIZABLE COLORS =====
:root { 
main-color: #057F95;
hover-color: #045B6B;
}


===== CUSTOMIZABLE IMAGES =====
IMPORTANT: EVERY URL MUST BE HTTPS:// IN ORDER TO WORK IN DISCORD
RECOMMENDATIONS: EVERY URL AT THE BOTTOM SHOULD BE THE SAME TO MAKE THE
tHEM MATCH. (YOUR CHOICE)
/*Change the url in .app to change the background behind chat */
.app { background-image: url("https://imgur.com/RG03PyX.png") !important;
background-size: cover !important; }

/*Change the url in .callout-backdrop to change the background when modal pop outs happen */

.callout-backdrop { background-color: black !important; background-image:     url("https://imgur.com/RG03PyX.png") !important; -webkit-transition: 0.3s all     ease; -o-transition: 0.3s all ease; -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease; transition:     0.3s all ease; background-size: cover !important; -webkit-filter:     brightness(75%); }

/*Change the urls below to change the background of a profile modal pop up     */

.user-popout:before {
    background-image: url("https://imgur.com/RG03PyX.png") !important;
    content: "";position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;height: 100%;width:     100%;z-index: -1;background-position: 50% 50%;-webkit-filter: blur(3px);-webkit-    transform: scale(1.05);transform: scale(1.05);}

#user-profile-modal .header:before {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), rgba(0, 0,     0, 0.5)), url("https://imgur.com/RG03PyX.png") !important;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), rgba(0, 0, 0,     0.5)), url("https://imgur.com/RG03PyX.png") !important;
    content: "";position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;width: 100%;height:     100%;z-index: -1;background-position: 50% 50%;background-size: cover     !important;-webkit-filter: blur(3px);-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);transform:     scale(1.1);}
```

I try diffrent things (color:transparent,transparency: true, rgba(0,0,0,0.1), visibility: hidden, opacity:0.5, make a transparent background and some other but none of them work.
I hope you can find a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can't.

This is because of the way Electron (the framework that Discord uses on desktop) works, the window you show content on needs to have a color. If you make it transparent, *it will just fallback to white or black*.

There are countermeasures for this, mainly shaders that copy what is behind the window and reflect it on it, but they use up a lot of computing (and they're also very overkill for one of your first programs).

Still, if anybody want to check it out:

- [electron-acrylic-window](https://github.com/Seo-Rii/electron-acrylic-window)
- [window-vibrancy](https://github.com/tauri-apps/window-vibrancy) for Tauri (not Electron, won't work on Discord)

Answer (score 0):

This is most definitely possible. Use BetterDiscord, then find someone elses theme that is modifiable and try to work from there. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xDMv.jpg here is a link as proof, of a transparent discord, over this post)

*I did not create this, here is the link to the exact theme https://betterdiscord.app/theme/Translucence . I wanted my own picture as the background so I went in and changed the url link for the image. However for a transparent background, there are probs other was to do this, but all i did was deleted characters from the img url, so it could not link to an image.

Uses no computing power at all, fast and easy, could probs setup in 5-10mins

ik super old post, but cause I saw a new response, that is not entirely correct, thought I would put this in here

Answer (score 0):

What you do with css affects the webpage, but can't control whole window behavior. I have managed doing what [@user19270840](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19270840/user19270840) has explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72500551/11868992), but it's not done with css alone. Betterdiscord has a switchable option: `Enable Transparency`.

Discord is an Electron app. To make an Electron app transparent, you have to either rely on an option within the app, edit the files (in case of discord, you have to look at the `app.asar` file, or use a mod like BetterDiscord) of the app, or create the app from scratch. The goal is to create the electron's `BrowserWindow` object with `transparency` option ([Link](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/window-customization#create-transparent-windows)). This will allow the app to have transparent elements, and work with a nice background image. But if you also want to get rid of [chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Chrome) to have complete transparency (i.e. seeing what's behind the application window), you should also set the `frame` option to `false`, and create a custom title bar if the app relies on os for it. (The [link](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/window-customization#create-frameless-windows) is the same page as transparency, on top.) Discord has its own title bar, so you don't need to create anew.

Note: For the ones who wants to build their own, there is [an issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/39959) which has been open for a couple of months, about a ghost title bar, just a heads-up.

Answer (score -1):

`color` is the property for the text color in the element. `background: transparent` is the one you're looking for.

Comment: when I insert     background: transparent  the background just go black

Answer (score -1):

You would want to use `background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.3)`, if you wanted a transparent red, etc.